# Ubuntu 23.10 slow wifi speed

Tags: drivers, 23.10

Recently I updated to Ubuntu 23.10, and slow wifi speed is bothering me. Even though I have a decent speed on Windows around 50mbps, but in Ubuntu I am getting a very low speed.

[image]

I check with `iwconfig` command and found out that my laptop was using the 2.5GHz band instead of 5GHz.

[image]

I tried changing the band from network settings, but it makes a copy of the wifi, I don't know why. Let's say my wifi is Home-Wifi, then if I change the band and restart I will be connected to Home-Wifi2, and so on. Meanwhile things are working well on Windows, but I want to fix things on Ubuntu.